# How to rotate the apache log files daily?

Tags: apache, ubuntu

I'm very new to apache. We wish to rotate the log files in daily basis. We installed the apache2 using :

```
sudo apt-get install apache2
```

in Ubuntu. Are there any ways to do it using `logrotate` ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In Ubuntu, you don't need to do anything - by default, logrotate is already pre-configured to rotate apache logs.

You can check and adjust logrotate configuration in file `/etc/logrotate.d/apache2`